# JRoute not working - always shows the current view

Tags: joomla-3.x, view, jroute

I have created a view for my custom component and it works OK however I've noticed that `JRoute` only works for the current view.

If I am, for example, on the view `picture` and I try to "JRoute another view", instead of showing this view I just "JRouted to", it shows the same `picture` view.

Example:

```
 JRoute("index.php?option=com_gallery&view=thumbnails")
```

Instead of showing mysite.com/thumbnails it shows mysite.com/picture. The same thing happens if I am on the view `thumbnail` and I do a `JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_gallery&view=picture")` instead of showing the view `picture` it shows the `thumbnail` view which means it works only for the current view.

I have tried using the Router file that comes with Joomla (in the com_users folder) but I could not get it working for me as it extends `JComponentRouterView` and the custom Router file I have for my component implements `JComponentRouterInterface`.

I tried:

```
$this->registerView(new JComponentRouterInterface('thumbnails'))
```

and I got:

> Call to undefined method  GalleryRouter::registerView()

Obviously `registerView` doesn't exist in `JComponentRouterInterface`

So I would like to know if there's any way to register or add my views to my router file or something I can do in order for them to be "recognised" in all views.

I'm currently using this workaround: `JURI::base()."my-menu-item"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to **add your own router.php** and **build your own views** in the **build + parse methods** in it. I would create a router.php file with this information: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#A_more_complex_Example

PS: I'd recommend to use name spacing to be compatible with future Joomla versions. It's possible since Joomla 3.8 + PHP 7.x. Instead of `JRoute` you would use `Route` and add `use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;` at the top of your script.

Comment: Yes I have done that. The problem is that I have been running into troubles because JRoute isn't yet very well-established. I have been running into some issues with different "JRoute documentations". But I will try again this one you recommended me as it extends `RouterBase` might solve my problems. The thing is that I need my custom component's url to work and I also need `JRoute` working for all views. I will upvote this for now. I will try that and I will accept your answer if it works. Thank you. By the way I have something similar in my Router file but it Implements instead of extending.